# How to do a Nokogiri search based on an XML attribute

Tags: ruby, xml, xpath, nokogiri

I'm trying to search through an XML file and display results based on whether an attribute exists in an nmap file.  I have the basic parsing working (or so I think), however my Ruby script is obviously incorrect since it's yielding the same results for every host in my file, even if the given XML field doesn't exist for a given host.

The XML file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE nmaprun>
<?xml-stylesheet href="file:///usr/local/bin/../share/nmap/nmap.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<!-- Nmap 7.12 scan initiated Mon May 23 15:53:44 2016 as: nmap -&#45;script /Users/me/Coding/nse_scripts/ssl-poodle.nse -oX poodle_results.txt 10.10.10.0/24 -->
<nmaprun scanner="nmap" args="nmap -&#45;script /Users/me/Coding/nse_scripts/ssl-poodle.nse -oX poodle_results.txt 10.10.10.0/24" start="1464033224" startstr="Mon May 23 15:53:44 2016" version="7.12" xmloutputversion="1.04">
<scaninfo type="connect" protocol="tcp" numservices="1000" services="1,3-4,6-7,9,13,17,19-26,30,32-33,37,42-43,49,53,70,79-85,88-90,99-100,106,109-111,113,119,125,135,139,143-144,146,161,163,179,199,211-212,222,254-256,259,264,280,301,306,311,340,366,389,406-407,416-417,425,427,443-445,458,464-465,481,497,500,512-515,524,541,543-545,548,554-555,563,587,593,616-617,625,631,636,646,648,666-668,683,687,691,700,705,711,714,720,722,726,749,765,777,783,787,800-801,808,843,873,880,888,898,900-903,911-912,981,987,990,992-993,995,999-1002,1007,1009-1011,1021-1100,1102,1104-1108,1110-1114,1117,1119,1121-1124,1126,1130-1132,1137-1138,1141,1145,1147-1149,1151-1152,1154,1163-1166,1169,1174-1175,1183,1185-1187,1192,1198-1199,1201,1213,1216-1218,1233-1234,1236,1244,1247-1248,1259,1271-1272,1277,1287,1296,1300-1301,1309-1311,1322,1328,1334,1352,1417,1433-1434,1443,1455,1461,1494,1500-1501,1503,1521,1524,1533,1556,1580,1583,1594,1600,1641,1658,1666,1687-1688,1700,1717-1721,1723,1755,1761,1782-1783,1801,1805,1812,1839-1840,1862-1864,1875,1900,1914,1935,1947,1971-1972,1974,1984,1998-2010,2013,2020-2022,2030,2033-2035,2038,2040-2043,2045-2049,2065,2068,2099-2100,2103,2105-2107,2111,2119,2121,2126,2135,2144,2160-2161,2170,2179,2190-2191,2196,2200,2222,2251,2260,2288,2301,2323,2366,2381-2383,2393-2394,2399,2401,2492,2500,2522,2525,2557,2601-2602,2604-2605,2607-2608,2638,2701-2702,2710,2717-2718,2725,2800,2809,2811,2869,2875,2909-2910,2920,2967-2968,2998,3000-3001,3003,3005-3007,3011,3013,3017,3030-3031,3052,3071,3077,3128,3168,3211,3221,3260-3261,3268-3269,3283,3300-3301,3306,3322-3325,3333,3351,3367,3369-3372,3389-3390,3404,3476,3493,3517,3527,3546,3551,3580,3659,3689-3690,3703,3737,3766,3784,3800-3801,3809,3814,3826-3828,3851,3869,3871,3878,3880,3889,3905,3914,3918,3920,3945,3971,3986,3995,3998,4000-4006,4045,4111,4125-4126,4129,4224,4242,4279,4321,4343,4443-4446,4449,4550,4567,4662,4848,4899-4900,4998,5000-5004,5009,5030,5033,5050-5051,5054,5060-5061,5080,5087,5100-5102,5120,5190,5200,5214,5221-5222,5225-5226,5269,5280,5298,5357,5405,5414,5431-5432,5440,5500,5510,5544,5550,5555,5560,5566,5631,5633,5666,5678-5679,5718,5730,5800-5802,5810-5811,5815,5822,5825,5850,5859,5862,5877,5900-5904,5906-5907,5910-5911,5915,5922,5925,5950,5952,5959-5963,5987-5989,5998-6007,6009,6025,6059,6100-6101,6106,6112,6123,6129,6156,6346,6389,6502,6510,6543,6547,6565-6567,6580,6646,6666-6669,6689,6692,6699,6779,6788-6789,6792,6839,6881,6901,6969,7000-7002,7004,7007,7019,7025,7070,7100,7103,7106,7200-7201,7402,7435,7443,7496,7512,7625,7627,7676,7741,7777-7778,7800,7911,7920-7921,7937-7938,7999-8002,8007-8011,8021-8022,8031,8042,8045,8080-8090,8093,8099-8100,8180-8181,8192-8194,8200,8222,8254,8290-8292,8300,8333,8383,8400,8402,8443,8500,8600,8649,8651-8652,8654,8701,8800,8873,8888,8899,8994,9000-9003,9009-9011,9040,9050,9071,9080-9081,9090-9091,9099-9103,9110-9111,9200,9207,9220,9290,9415,9418,9485,9500,9502-9503,9535,9575,9593-9595,9618,9666,9876-9878,9898,9900,9917,9929,9943-9944,9968,9998-10004,10009-10010,10012,10024-10025,10082,10180,10215,10243,10566,10616-10617,10621,10626,10628-10629,10778,11110-11111,11967,12000,12174,12265,12345,13456,13722,13782-13783,14000,14238,14441-14442,15000,15002-15004,15660,15742,16000-16001,16012,16016,16018,16080,16113,16992-16993,17877,17988,18040,18101,18988,19101,19283,19315,19350,19780,19801,19842,20000,20005,20031,20221-20222,20828,21571,22939,23502,24444,24800,25734-25735,26214,27000,27352-27353,27355-27356,27715,28201,30000,30718,30951,31038,31337,32768-32785,33354,33899,34571-34573,35500,38292,40193,40911,41511,42510,44176,44442-44443,44501,45100,48080,49152-49161,49163,49165,49167,49175-49176,49400,49999-50003,50006,50300,50389,50500,50636,50800,51103,51493,52673,52822,52848,52869,54045,54328,55055-55056,55555,55600,56737-56738,57294,57797,58080,60020,60443,61532,61900,62078,63331,64623,64680,65000,65129,65389"/>
<verbose level="0"/>
<debugging level="0"/>
<host starttime="1464033224" endtime="1464034228"><status state="up" reason="syn-ack" reason_ttl="0"/>
<address addr="10.10.10.1" addrtype="ipv4"/>
<hostnames>
<hostname name="DD-WRT" type="PTR"/>
</hostnames>
<ports><extraports state="closed" count="996">
<extrareasons reason="conn-refused" count="996"/>
</extraports>
<port protocol="tcp" portid="22"><state state="open" reason="syn-ack" reason_ttl="0"/><service name="ssh" method="table" conf="3"/></port>
<port protocol="tcp" portid="53"><state state="open" reason="syn-ack" reason_ttl="0"/><service name="domain" method="table" conf="3"/></port>
<port protocol="tcp" portid="80"><state state="open" reason="syn-ack" reason_ttl="0"/><service name="http" method="table" conf="3"/></port>
<port protocol="tcp" portid="443"><state state="open" reason="syn-ack" reason_ttl="0"/><service name="https" method="table" conf="3"/><script id="ssl-poodle" output="&#xa;  VULNERABLE:&#xa;  SSL POODLE information leak&#xa;    State: VULNERABLE&#xa;    IDs:  OSVDB:113251  CVE:CVE-2014-3566&#xa;          The SSL protocol 3.0, as used in OpenSSL through 1.0.1i and&#xa;          other products, uses nondeterministic CBC padding, which makes it easier&#xa;          for man-in-the-middle attackers to obtain cleartext data via a&#xa;          padding-oracle attack, aka the &quot;POODLE&quot; issue.&#xa;    Disclosure date: 2014-10-14&#xa;    Check results:&#xa;      TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA&#xa;    References:&#xa;      https://www.imperialviolet.org/2014/10/14/poodle.html&#xa;      http://osvdb.org/113251&#xa;      https://www.openssl.org/~bodo/ssl-poodle.pdf&#xa;      https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2014-3566&#xa;"><table key="CVE-2014-3566">
<elem key="title">SSL POODLE information leak</elem>
<elem key="state">VULNERABLE</elem>
<table key="ids">
<elem>OSVDB:113251</elem>
<elem>CVE:CVE-2014-3566</elem>
</table>
<table key="description">
<elem>    The SSL protocol 3.0, as used in OpenSSL through 1.0.1i and&#xa;    other products, uses nondeterministic CBC padding, which makes it easier&#xa;    for man-in-the-middle attackers to obtain cleartext data via a&#xa;    padding-oracle attack, aka the &quot;POODLE&quot; issue.</elem>
</table>
<table key="dates">
<table key="disclosure">
<elem key="day">14</elem>
<elem key="month">10</elem>
<elem key="year">2014</elem>
</table>
</table>
<elem key="disclosure">2014-10-14</elem>
<table key="check_results">
<elem>TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA</elem>
</table>
<table key="refs">
<elem>https://www.imperialviolet.org/2014/10/14/poodle.html</elem>
<elem>http://osvdb.org/113251</elem>
<elem>https://www.openssl.org/~bodo/ssl-poodle.pdf</elem>
<elem>https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2014-3566</elem>
</table>
</table>
</script></port>
</ports>
<times srtt="17618" rttvar="3666" to="100000"/>
</host>

<host starttime="1464033224" endtime="1464034228"><status state="up" reason="conn-refused" reason_ttl="0"/>
<address addr="10.10.10.100" addrtype="ipv4"/>
<hostnames>
</hostnames>
<ports><extraports state="closed" count="1000">
<extrareasons reason="conn-refused" count="1000"/>
</extraports>
</ports>
<times srtt="15580" rttvar="11919" to="100000"/>
</host>

<host starttime="1464033224" endtime="1464034228"><status state="up" reason="conn-refused" reason_ttl="0"/>
<address addr="10.10.10.101" addrtype="ipv4"/>
<hostnames>
<hostname name="office" type="PTR"/>
</hostnames>
<ports><extraports state="closed" count="999">
<extrareasons reason="conn-refused" count="999"/>
</extraports>
<port protocol="tcp" portid="22"><state state="open" reason="syn-ack" reason_ttl="0"/><service name="ssh" method="table" conf="3"/></port>
</ports>
<times srtt="12241" rttvar="4711" to="100000"/>
</host>

<host starttime="1464033224" endtime="1464034228"><status state="up" reason="conn-refused" reason_ttl="0"/>
<address addr="10.10.10.104" addrtype="ipv4"/>
<hostnames>
<hostname name="main" type="PTR"/>
</hostnames>
<ports><extraports state="closed" count="999">
<extrareasons reason="conn-refused" count="999"/>
</extraports>
<port protocol="tcp" portid="22"><state state="open" reason="syn-ack" reason_ttl="0"/><service name="ssh" method="table" conf="3"/></port>
</ports>
<times srtt="14409" rttvar="1988" to="100000"/>
</host>

<host starttime="1464033224" endtime="1464034228"><status state="up" reason="conn-refused" reason_ttl="0"/>
<address addr="10.10.10.115" addrtype="ipv4"/>
<hostnames>
<hostname name="c8d10f5c386d4e4bb01d7aa0edac7a24" type="PTR"/>
</hostnames>
<ports><extraports state="closed" count="998">
<extrareasons reason="conn-refused" count="998"/>
</extraports>
<port protocol="tcp" portid="22"><state state="open" reason="syn-ack" reason_ttl="0"/><service name="ssh" method="table" conf="3"/></port>
<port protocol="tcp" portid="10000"><state state="open" reason="syn-ack" reason_ttl="0"/><service name="snet-sensor-mgmt" method="table" conf="3"/></port>
</ports>
<times srtt="4009" rttvar="2037" to="100000"/>
</host>

<host starttime="1464033224" endtime="1464034228"><status state="up" reason="syn-ack" reason_ttl="0"/>
<address addr="10.10.10.121" addrtype="ipv4"/>
<hostnames>
<hostname name="OpenELEC" type="PTR"/>
</hostnames>
<ports><extraports state="closed" count="995">
<extrareasons reason="conn-refused" count="995"/>
</extraports>
<port protocol="tcp" portid="22"><state state="open" reason="syn-ack" reason_ttl="0"/><service name="ssh" method="table" conf="3"/></port>
<port protocol="tcp" portid="80"><state state="open" reason="syn-ack" reason_ttl="0"/><service name="http" method="table" conf="3"/></port>
<port protocol="tcp" portid="111"><state state="open" reason="syn-ack" reason_ttl="0"/><service name="rpcbind" method="table" conf="3"/></port>
<port protocol="tcp" portid="445"><state state="open" reason="syn-ack" reason_ttl="0"/><service name="microsoft-ds" method="table" conf="3"/></port>
<port protocol="tcp" portid="1049"><state state="open" reason="syn-ack" reason_ttl="0"/><service name="td-postman" method="table" conf="3"/></port>
</ports>
<times srtt="11099" rttvar="4538" to="100000"/>
</host>

<host starttime="1464033224" endtime="1464033238"><status state="up" reason="conn-refused" reason_ttl="0"/>
<address addr="10.10.10.130" addrtype="ipv4"/>
<hostnames>
<hostname name="Justins-iMac" type="PTR"/>
</hostnames>
<ports><extraports state="closed" count="1000">
<extrareasons reason="conn-refused" count="1000"/>
</extraports>
</ports>
<times srtt="455" rttvar="155" to="100000"/>
</host>

<host starttime="1464033224" endtime="1464034248"><status state="up" reason="conn-refused" reason_ttl="0"/>
<address addr="10.10.10.135" addrtype="ipv4"/>
<hostnames>
<hostname name="HarmonyHub" type="PTR"/>
</hostnames>
<ports><extraports state="closed" count="997">
<extrareasons reason="conn-refused" count="997"/>
</extraports>
<port protocol="tcp" portid="5222"><state state="open" reason="syn-ack" reason_ttl="0"/><service name="xmpp-client" method="table" conf="3"/></port>
<port protocol="tcp" portid="8088"><state state="open" reason="syn-ack" reason_ttl="0"/><service name="radan-http" method="table" conf="3"/></port>
<port protocol="tcp" portid="8222"><state state="open" reason="syn-ack" reason_ttl="0"/><service name="unknown" method="table" conf="3"/></port>
</ports>
<times srtt="28872" rttvar="2401" to="100000"/>
</host>

<host starttime="1464033224" endtime="1464034228"><status state="up" reason="syn-ack" reason_ttl="0"/>
<address addr="10.10.10.137" addrtype="ipv4"/>
<hostnames>
<hostname name="HP1A4DC4" type="PTR"/>
</hostnames>
<ports><extraports state="closed" count="985">
<extrareasons reason="conn-refused" count="985"/>
</extraports>
<port protocol="tcp" portid="80"><state state="open" reason="syn-ack" reason_ttl="0"/><service name="http" method="table" conf="3"/></port>
<port protocol="tcp" portid="139"><state state="open" reason="syn-ack" reason_ttl="0"/><service name="netbios-ssn" method="table" conf="3"/></port>
<port protocol="tcp" portid="443"><state state="open" reason="syn-ack" reason_ttl="0"/><service name="https" method="table" conf="3"/></port>
<port protocol="tcp" portid="445"><state state="open" reason="syn-ack" reason_ttl="0"/><service name="microsoft-ds" method="table" conf="3"/></port>
<port protocol="tcp" portid="631"><state state="open" reason="syn-ack" reason_ttl="0"/><service name="ipp" method="table" conf="3"/></port>
<port protocol="tcp" portid="6839"><state state="open" reason="syn-ack" reason_ttl="0"/><service name="unknown" method="table" conf="3"/></port>
<port protocol="tcp" portid="7435"><state state="open" reason="syn-ack" reason_ttl="0"/><service name="unknown" method="table" conf="3"/></port>
<port protocol="tcp" portid="8080"><state state="open" reason="syn-ack" reason_ttl="0"/><service name="http-proxy" method="table" conf="3"/></port>
<port protocol="tcp" portid="9100"><state state="open" reason="syn-ack" reason_ttl="0"/><service name="jetdirect" method="table" conf="3"/></port>
<port protocol="tcp" portid="9101"><state state="open" reason="syn-ack" reason_ttl="0"/><service name="jetdirect" method="table" conf="3"/></port>
<port protocol="tcp" portid="9102"><state state="open" reason="syn-ack" reason_ttl="0"/><service name="jetdirect" method="table" conf="3"/></port>
<port protocol="tcp" portid="9110"><state state="open" reason="syn-ack" reason_ttl="0"/><service name="unknown" method="table" conf="3"/></port>
<port protocol="tcp" portid="9111"><state state="open" reason="syn-ack" reason_ttl="0"/><service name="DragonIDSConsole" method="table" conf="3"/></port>
<port protocol="tcp" portid="9220"><state state="open" reason="syn-ack" reason_ttl="0"/><service name="unknown" method="table" conf="3"/></port>
<port protocol="tcp" portid="9290"><state state="open" reason="syn-ack" reason_ttl="0"/><service name="unknown" method="table" conf="3"/></port>
</ports>
<times srtt="6912" rttvar="5486" to="100000"/>
</host>

<host starttime="1464033224" endtime="1464034228"><status state="up" reason="conn-refused" reason_ttl="0"/>
<address addr="10.10.10.144" addrtype="ipv4"/>
<hostnames>
<hostname name="time-capsule" type="PTR"/>
</hostnames>
<ports><extraports state="closed" count="995">
<extrareasons reason="conn-refused" count="995"/>
</extraports>
<port protocol="tcp" portid="139"><state state="open" reason="syn-ack" reason_ttl="0"/><service name="netbios-ssn" method="table" conf="3"/></port>
<port protocol="tcp" portid="445"><state state="open" reason="syn-ack" reason_ttl="0"/><service name="microsoft-ds" method="table" conf="3"/></port>
<port protocol="tcp" portid="548"><state state="open" reason="syn-ack" reason_ttl="0"/><service name="afp" method="table" conf="3"/></port>
<port protocol="tcp" portid="5009"><state state="open" reason="syn-ack" reason_ttl="0"/><service name="airport-admin" method="table" conf="3"/></port>
<port protocol="tcp" portid="10000"><state state="open" reason="syn-ack" reason_ttl="0"/><service name="snet-sensor-mgmt" method="table" conf="3"/></port>
</ports>
<times srtt="24675" rttvar="20640" to="107235"/>
</host>

<runstats><finished time="1464034248" timestr="Mon May 23 16:10:48 2016" elapsed="1024.26" summary="Nmap done at Mon May 23 16:10:48 2016; 256 IP addresses (10 hosts up) scanned in 1024.26 seconds" exit="success"/><hosts up="10" down="246" total="256"/>
</runstats>
</nmaprun>
```

My Ruby script is:

```
require 'nokogiri'

document = Nokogiri::XML(File.open("poodle_results.txt"))

document.xpath("//host").each do |host|
  ip_address = host.at_xpath("address[@addrtype='ipv4']").at_xpath("@addr").value
  result =  host.at_xpath("//ports//elem[@key='state']").content
  puts "#{ip_address} #{result}"
end
```

In this file there are 10 hosts, but only one that has the `<elem key="state">` tag.  However my output looks like:

```
10.10.10.1 VULNERABLE
10.10.10.100 VULNERABLE
10.10.10.101 VULNERABLE
10.10.10.104 VULNERABLE
10.10.10.115 VULNERABLE
10.10.10.121 VULNERABLE
10.10.10.130 VULNERABLE
10.10.10.135 VULNERABLE
10.10.10.137 VULNERABLE
10.10.10.144 VULNERABLE
```

I'm confused at this point about what I've done wrong, since it's clearly iterating over each host.  The last 9 hosts shown don't have the `<elem key="state">` tag within their `<host></host>` section, so they should not be included in the output.

If the `<elem key="state">` tag doesn't exist, I'd expect the outcome to just list the hosts that do have the key and it equals "VULNERABLE".

```
10.10.10.1 VULNERABLE
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. When asking, we need you to reduce your input data to the _bare minimum_ necessary to demonstrate the problem. Anything beyond that wastes our time as we have to search through it and throw away anything not directly involved. Please read "[mcve]". Help us help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gives you the correct XPath initially, so that you don't have to expend the effort looping through mismatched elements to get your results:

```
document.xpath("//host[.//elem/@key='state']").each do |host|
  ip_address = host.at_xpath("address[@addrtype='ipv4']").at_xpath("@addr").value
  result =  host.at_xpath("//ports//elem[@key='state']").content
  puts "#{ip_address} #{result}"
end
```

This chooses all of the `host` elements that have a sub-element with a `key` attribute with a 'state' value.  No need to check for correct matches within the loop, because this will actually only return the elements that you want.  It's a complete XPath solution to your question.

Comment: Oh, that's sweet... much more efficient!

Comment: Yeah, and if you have a pile of nmap logs, this can run an order of magnitude faster.  Save some CPU time and cut down on your cooling bills. :D

Answer (score 0):

Remove '//' from elem finder

```
document.xpath("//host").each do |host|
  ip_address = host.at_xpath("address[@addrtype='ipv4']").at_xpath("@addr").value
  path = host.at_xpath("ports//elem[@key='state']")
  next unless path
  puts "#{ip_address} #{result}" if path.content
end
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was missing.